# Referencing a cell by using a formula to get the name of the cell

Tags: excel, cell, formula

I'm not sure how to describe this question but an example should make it clear:

```
"A"&COUNT(A1:A10000)
```

gives A10000. So why can't I just do:

```
SUM(A1:"A"&COUNT(A1:A10000))
```

which should be the same as `SUM(A1:A10000)`?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNT(A1:A10000)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

USe the indirect function to convert cell address to range reference:

```
=sum(indirect("A1:A"&COUNT(A1:A10000)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) is considered a *volatile* function. You can accomplish the same thing with the non-volatile [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) using the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) to find the last number in a column (in case of interim blanks or interspersed text) rather than counting the numbers in a column.

```
=sum(A1:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1e99, A:A)))
```

The results should be similar to the following.

[image: SUM INDIRECT RANGE]

Comment: Great example. You wrote that the MATCH function can be used to find the last number in a column. The code given for this is "MATCH(1e99, A:A)". Am I correct in saying that 1e99 references the last number in a column?

Comment: That would not be accurate. `1E+99` is a *1* followed by 99 zeroes and would more accurately be described as *the number that will never be reached*. The MATCH function (with the default as the *match_type*) keeps trying to reach it with every number it finds in the column until it gives up and returns the row number of the last number.

Answer (score 1):

Because you combine int and string, the result become string and it's can't act as a cell no.

give in detail

```
"A"&COUNT(A1:A10000) gives A10000
```

1. COUNT(A1:10000) = it's count all cell that has value, supposed all cell in column A has value then it will show result as '10,000'
2. you try to combine String 'A' and int '10,000' so it become String 'A10000'
3. the String 'A10000' is not same as int anymore, it's can't use to sum, divide or multiply since it become String.

   - (ex1. "A"&10000 = String "A10000" is not same as CELL A10000 )
   - (ex2. int 5 = number 5,  String '5' = word 'FIVE' )

---

```
SUM(A1:"A"&COUNT(A1:A10000))
```

4. next, the second row you are trying to use it as a cell row number.
5. since it is String and it's not a cell row number, so it's can't sum it as CELL A1, A10000 for you.

Comment: Great explanation, I will be attentive to data types.